# Updating dependency within dependency in package-lock.json

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, package-lock.json

On Github, I received a notification saying

> Upgrade trim-newlines to version 3.0.1 or later.

It's not in my `package.json`, so when I looked up where it was using `npm ls trim-newlines`, I found that it was in `node_modules/meow` which shows up as:

```
└─┬ node-sass@5.0.0
  └── meow@3.7.0
```

So since `trim-newlines` is a dependency of `meow`, how can I update it? I've tried `npm i trim-newlines --package-lock-only` but that only seems to install it as a new package rather than update it.

Any solutions? Thanks in advance!